Is MassTransit with Azure Service Bus a good fit for tenant-isolated on-prem agents?
We are using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus in our backend system for messaging. Now, we need to extend our solution to communicate with on-premises agents that will be installed for each of our tenants. These agents should receive messages specifically targeted to them.
Here are our requirements for this setup:

Tenant Isolation: Each agent (representing a tenant) should only have access to messages intended for that tenant (e.g., queue isolation - SAS token?).
Centralized Queue Management: The backend system must handle queue creation and lifecycle management, ensuring that the process is seamless and automated. The agent should only be able to read and write.

Given these requirements, is Azure Service Bus together with MassTransit a suitable choice for implementing the messaging between our backend system and tenant-specific on-prem agents?
If yes, what are the best practices for achieving tenant isolation and managing the queues efficiently? A boilerplate example would be greatly appreciated to help us get started.
If not, what alternative solutions might better fit this scenario?
Elaboration:
We provide a SaaS service hosted in the Azure cloud. To automate specific tasks for our customers, we need to execute actions within their datacenters. This requires a request-response setup, where the cloud solution sends a request to an agent, and the agent responds upon task completion.
Customers install the agent using a installer on their Windows Server machine. During installation, they are prompted to enter a “connection string” (potentially a SAS token) to securely connect to the cloud solution. This process also allows the agent to “announce” itself to the cloud, enabling the cloud solution to recognize and communicate with the new agent.


Have you tried any approach so far? @SOK

Yes, we attempted the following approach: the backend system successfully created tenant-specific queues. However, we are currently encountering issues with the agents connecting to the queues using queue-specific shared access policies with MassTransit.

Ok so you have tried the portal approach only! @SOK

MassTransit requires Manage access to Azure Service Bus, so I'm doubtful you'll get it working with limited permissions.

Thanks, Chris for your quick answer. I think we need to rethink our overall solution design for this :)

Most probably MassTransit andf Service bus answers to your needs.
However, would be better if you could share some more details, use case, what do you want to achieve? Maybe there are other pragmatic solutions?
Would be great if you share MassTransit and service bus configuration and some consumer classes. So I can get the idea from the context :)
So my comment to this abstract question as is follows:
The general idea is creating tenant specific queue and using SAS token. In agent configuration they will connect to service bus with the SAS token.

SAS tokens can be generated programmatically at the backend or in pipeline with powershell script. Again, please share more details what is the eventual intention here?

@JavidGahramanov: Thank you for taking the time to review this. I have updated the question above to provide more details about the overall solution setup.

Thanks for adding details.  What permissions have you set for Shared access policies? Send | Listen? No Manage?

Send and Listen because the agent will live in an external environment which potentially could be targeted by bad actors

Then add additional layer (proxy). Function app for example or with API manager, with JWT
